# Search with text

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a tagging system

```
 CREATE TABLE `blog` (
`id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`body` text NOT NULL,
`tags` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

for each blog I add tags in tags like tag1,tag2,tag3.

```
<?=escapeHTML($POST['ATTR']['TAGS'])?>
```

this function displays multiple texts. Like a cars,vehicles,ford

how could i create a link for each text?

For example when I click on cars to send me on mydomain.com/search/cars

Comment: generate `a` elements with each tag in your loop , put the tag variable in the `a`  `href` attribute

Answer (score 0):

for example like that

```
$tags = explode(',',escapeHTML($POST['ATTR']['TAGS']));

foreach($tags as $tag){

    echo "<a href='".$tag."'>".$tag."</a>";
}
```

Split the String with Tags into an array.

Use a foreach loop to ouput a link foreach tag.